# Recency, Frequency and Monetary Value Analysis with rfm Package in R Shiny

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to implement the `rfm` package for Recency, Frequency and Monetary Value Analysis and i am having problems with "date" transformation to make the package work.

I have tried the code below in shiny and the issues seems to be with the date field being imported from MySQL with a reactivePoll function

I have the following dataset to be used with Transactional data with the package rfm:

```r
rfmdata <- tibble::tribble(
             ~CustomerID,                 ~Date, ~Revenue,
                   14159, "2011-07-13 12:06:00",   419.48,
                   14110, "2011-07-13 12:06:00",    317.4,
                   15530, "2011-07-13 12:15:00",   177.85,
                   16779, "2011-07-13 12:18:00",   660.01,
                   16225, "2011-07-13 12:18:00",   353.08,
                   12528, "2011-07-13 12:24:00",   281.71,
                   13089, "2011-07-13 12:27:00",    214.2,
                   18121, "2011-07-13 12:53:00",    23.25,
                   14502, "2011-07-13 13:14:00",   105.78,
                   12935, "2011-07-13 13:16:00",   353.09,
                   13149, "2011-07-13 13:20:00",   506.16,
                   15311, "2011-07-13 13:27:00",   152.81,
                   18219, "2011-07-13 13:33:00",   185.85,
                   12766, "2011-07-13 13:37:00",   936.48,
                   14088, "2011-07-13 13:56:00",   -76.32,
                   18245, "2011-07-13 14:28:00",   330.92,
                   18245, "2011-07-13 14:29:00",     35.6,
                   13777, "2011-07-13 14:39:00",    270.9,
                   14221, "2011-07-13 15:04:00",   357.78,
                   14221, "2011-07-13 15:05:00",     17.4,
                   14201, "2011-07-13 15:18:00",   110.14,
                   18225, "2011-07-13 15:29:00",    488.4,
                   12415, "2011-07-13 15:30:00",  2735.16,
                   12415, "2011-07-13 15:31:00",     61.2,
                   13667, "2011-07-13 15:42:00",   305.02,
                   14400, "2011-07-13 15:50:00",    574.7,
                   17644, "2011-07-13 16:47:00",   316.85,
                   17644, "2011-07-13 16:48:00",     39.6,
                   17567, "2011-07-13 17:03:00",   461.08,
                   12405, "2011-07-14 08:52:00",  1710.39,
                   14265, "2011-07-14 09:10:00",   252.05,
                   17738, "2011-07-14 09:22:00",   585.62,
                   17738, "2011-07-14 09:23:00",   205.95,
                   17389, "2011-07-14 09:26:00",    561.9,
                   16719, "2011-07-14 09:54:00",    308.2,
                   13012, "2011-07-14 09:58:00",   304.92,
                   15125, "2011-07-14 10:08:00",   315.12,
                   15125, "2011-07-14 10:09:00",    49.92,
                   13577, "2011-07-14 10:11:00",   465.35,
                   17315, "2011-07-14 10:15:00",   112.81,
                   14426, "2011-07-14 10:19:00",  -500.74,
                   17396, "2011-07-14 10:20:00",    791.7,
                   17396, "2011-07-14 10:20:00",   1960.8,
                   17396, "2011-07-14 10:21:00",   1037.1,
                   17396, "2011-07-14 10:21:00",    596.7,
                   17396, "2011-07-14 10:24:00",       18,
                   16701, "2011-07-14 10:27:00",  -119.76
             )
```

This data is coming from MySQL database which is fetched via reactivePoll every 30 minutes as follows:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
             user = ('root'),
             password = ('ruvimboML55AMG'),
             host = ('localhost'),
             dbname = ('healthcare_mining'))
```

```r
    get_rfmData <- function(con) {
      RFM_data_orders <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT CustomerID, Date,              sum(Amount) as Revenue FROM onlineRetail WHERE CustomerID is not null                    Group by CustomerID, Date;")
  }
     # Reactive poll for rfm data every 30 min
     RFM_data_orders <- reactivePoll(1800000, session,
                            checkFunc = function(){
                              print("Entered Check")
                              Sys.time()
                              print(Sys.time())
                              # get max date from database table to        determine if data has been updated
                              max_date <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT        MAX(date_updated) FROM onlineRetail as updated_last;")
                              return(max_date)
                            },
                            valueFunc = function(){
                              print("Entered Value")
                              Sys.time()
                              print(Sys.time())
                              get_rfmData(con)
                            }

  )
```

Next i need to create a data table which gives the rfm data from          the reactive poll data with the following code:

```r
    # Customer Recency, Frequency and Monetary Analytics
    output$rfmAnalytics <- DT::renderDataTable({
      req(credentials()$user_auth)
      withProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                   detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                     for (i in 1:15) {
                       incProgress(1/15)
                       Sys.sleep(20)
                     }
                   })

      analysis_date <-  lubridate::as_date(today(),tz = 'CAT')
      RFM_data_orders() %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')) %>%
      rfm_result <- rfm_table_order(RFM_data_orders(), CustomerID, Date,     Revenue, analysis_date)
      rfm_result
      DT::datatable(rfm_result$rfm)
      })
```

I am getting the following error message:

```r
Warning: Error in -: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

This should be something to do with the 'Date' field which i think     is not being converted to the 'date' format and remains in the 'char' as imported from MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solutions as follows:

```
# Store RFM Data reactively
    dataRFM <- reactive({
    RFM_data_orders() %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
```

})

Use reactive in the code:

```r
 # Customer Recency, Frequency and Monetary Analytics
        output$rfmAnalytics <- DT::renderDataTable({
           req(credentials()$user_auth)
          withProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                   detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                     for (i in 1:15) {
                       incProgress(1/15)
                       Sys.sleep(20)
                     }
                   })

          analysis_date <-  lubridate::as_date(today(),tz = 'CAT')
          rfm_result <- rfm_table_order(dataRFM(), CustomerID, Date, Revenue,     analysis_date)
          rfm_result
          DT::datatable(rfm_result$rfm)
          })


<sup>Created on 2019-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)
```